# Remove commas within numbers only

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a list of product sales (and their cost) which have frustratingly been concatenated into a single string, separated by commas. I ultimately need to separate out each product into unique rows which is easy enough with `stringr::str_split`.

However, the cost associated with each product has comma to show thousands e.g. 1,000.00 or 38,647.89. Therefore `str_split` is splitting products incorrectly as it hits commas within a product's cost.

I was wondering what the best `tidyverse` solution would be to remove all commas which are *surrounded* by numbers so that 1,000.00 becomes 1000.00 and 38,647.89 becomes 38647.89. Once these commas are removed I can `str_split` on the commas which delimit the products and thus split each unique product into its own row.

Here is a dummy dataset:

```
df<-data.frame(id = c(1, 2), product = c("1 Car at $38,678.49, 1 Truck at $78,468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5,634.78", "1 Car at $38,678.49, 1 Truck at $78,468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5,634.78"))

df

  id                                                              product
1 1 Car at $38,678.49, 1 Truck at $78,468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5,634.78
2 1 Car at $38,678.49, 1 Truck at $78,468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5,634.78
```

Expected outcome:

```
  id                                                              product
1  1 1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78
2  2 1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78
```

Comment: Good point and I should imagine this would work most of the time, to be honest with you. However, I cannot guarantee that a space will *always* follow a comma so I'm thinking that the safest bet would be to remove all commas within numbers first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
df %>%
  mutate(product = product %>% str_replace_all("([0-9]),([0-9])", "\\1\\2"))
```

**Result**

```
  id                                                           product
1  1 1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78
2  2 1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78
```

Comment: Looks looks ideal, thank you. One question: what does `"\\1\\2"` do in your code?

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's within  `tidyverse`.

Comment: They are references to the matched numbers within the parentheses, which are returned again as the replacement (without the comma between them).

Answer (score 1):

```
> apply(df,1,function(x){gsub(",([0-9])","\\1",x[2])})

[1] "1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78"
[2] "1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78"
```

Answer (score 0):

A way via base R can be,

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$product), ' '), function(i)paste(sub(',', '', i), collapse = ' '))
#[1] "1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78" "1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but your code removes all commas, not just those within numbers. My downstream code using `stringr::str_split` will therefore not work as I can't split on the commas between products.

Comment: Sorry. Minor typo. I meant to use `sub` not the global one.Check it now

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)
df$product <- str_replace_all(df$product, "(?<=\\d),(?=\\d)", "")
df
  id                                                           product
1  1 1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78
2  2 1 Car at $38678.49, 1 Truck at $78468.00, 1 Motorbike at $5634.78
```